# Что такое куш?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Про человека, которому удалось заполучить (например, в игре или путем коммерческой сделки) крупную сумму денег или еще каких-то материальных благ, говорят, что он "сорвал куш". Чаще, насколько я знаю, это выражение употребляется именно по отношению к игре.
И хотелось бы знать, что такое "куш", в смысле, какое происхождение у этого слова и родственно ли оно слову "кушать"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кажется, в данном случае мы имеем дело с *нижегородским французским*. Современные французско-русские словари совершенно не знают такого значения слова **couche** : ставка, выигрыш в картах.

> **КУШ**
> (фр.). 1) ставка в игре, также в закладах; выигрыш и проигрыши в один удар. 2) известная денежная сумма. 3) охотничье приказание собаке: смирно, ляг, лежать, молчать.
>
> (Источник: "Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка". Чудинов А.Н., 1910)

Вполне вероятно, что этот якобы французский карточный термин придуман самими русскими. Какое значение слова было взято за основу игроками?

> **couche** [к у ш]
> 1. ложе, постель
> 2. пласт; слой тж перен
> 3. оболочка; пленка; покрытие; прокладка
> 4. (чаще pl) роды
> 5. пеленка, подгузник
> 6. унавоженная грядка, теплая гряда, парник
> 7. разг бестолочь
> 8. прослойка
> 9. подготовка (под основание)
> 10. грунтовка
> 11. лежень

Поищем слово *куш* в Словаре РЯ 18 века :

> **КУШЬ** 1798, межд. Фр. couche — ложись. Охот. Как приказание собаке лечь и затихнуть. У нас говорится кушь, кушь. Ад. I 957.
> http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/11/slb09607.htm

Только собачья команда, карточного термина еще нет. В Словаре 1847 читаем :

> **Кушъ**, ставка денегъ между игроками.

Можно предположить, что перед очередным коном игры участники **выкладывали** свои ставки на ломберный стол, отсюда и словцо появилось. Ср : поставить (ставка) - положить (couche). Французский язык был основным в такого рода компаниях игроков, вот они и приспособили его под свою игру.  Но слово чисто русское получилось, со своим оригинальным значением.

Answer (score 2):

Из этимологического словаря Фасмера:

> > КУШ
> >
> > "ставка, выигрыш" (Мельников), из франц. соuсhе – то же; также куш – межд. "смирно! лежать!" (собаке), охотничий язык (Даль). Из франц. соuсhе от соuсhеr "класть, ложиться", лат. соllосārе.

Answer (score 1):

coucher [kuʃe]
1.укладывать, класть (в постель);
2.*карт* ставить; 
 'coucher gros' — делать большую ставку (на карту)

Comment: Только один момент. В французском языке слово *couche* не имеет значения "ставка в игре". Куш французы называют **lot** или **magot**.

Comment: Никаких моментов, куш это то, что на столе лежит.
 Куча тоже лежит, совпадение смысла, кучу тоже кладут. И еще надо посмотреть, откуда этимология французского слова.
В болгарском овчарня - кошара, есть и русское слово кош.

Comment: КОШ
м. сиб. кошница, корзина; вор. род большой корзины для ловли рыбы и раков (см. кошница). | Южн. плетеный шалаш, балаган; | загон, овчарня; | оренб. кошар (см. кошара), малая, холостая кибитка; вообще: табор, стоянка, стань, становище, казачий обоз, лагерь, стойбище. У запорожских казаков кошем звали селенье, станицу (стан), а кошевой был начальник коша, станичный атаман...... |

Еще Даль забыл про объединяющее слово, лежбище, как место ночевки.
Вот похоже оттуда и смысл французского. Да и не похоже, а наверняка.

Comment: А есть еще Кошель.

кошель коше́ль род. п. -ля́, кошелёк, укр. кошíль, род. п. -еля́, сербохорв. ко́шље мн. "забор", словен. košúlja "корзина", польск. koszaɫka. От кош II; см. Мi. ЕW 426; Бернекер 1, 587. Диал. кошо́лка "корзинка", ряз. (РФВ 68, 12). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

тоже Приспособление для ловли рыбы,

по какой- то интересной причине в мальтийском - tartaruni.

Слово LOT тоже не французское.