# Можно ли "поднять куш"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Есть устойчивый фразеологизм — "сорвать куш". Но если сказать "поднять куш" будет ли это ошибкой?

Answer (score 1):

Будет. Потому и фразеологизм, что нельзя менять ни одного слова: устойчивое словосочетание.

Но я его - поднятый куш - выгуглила:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понятно, как возникла такая ошибка. Если не ошибаюсь, название ей - контаминация. *(Сорвать банк - [сорвать ставку](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1034437/21/Shubinskiy_Valeriy_-_Gapon.html) - сорвать куш - поднять банк - поднять ставку - поднять куш.)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Это я сама себя проверяла - можно ли "поднять банк"?)

Слово "куш" употреблено [во втором его значении](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88&all=x) - синоним ставке в игре, а не просто некая (изрядная) денежная сумма.

Ставка может быть копеечной; её можно поднимать. А вот куш в том же значении - нельзя.

(По крайней мере я не нашла зафиксированным в компетентных источниках "поднятый куш".)

---

Нашла здесь, на сайте, **[вопрос об этимологии слова "куш"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/41366/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88)**.

Лучшим ответом предположено, что

> перед очередным коном игры участники выкладывали свои ставки на
>   ломберный стол, отсюда и словцо появилось. Ср.: *поставить (ставка) -
>   положить (couche)*. Французский язык был основным в такого рода
>   компаниях игроков, вот они и приспособили его под свою игру.

Comment: Если ставка = куш, то почему его нельзя поднять?   "Забрав деньги, он отсчитал положенные комиссионные и вышел из-за стола. Всегда важно знать, когда следует закончить игру, а поднятый куш должен поставить неплохую завершающую точку".  Евгений Сухов, "Аристократ обмана"